# Running multiple services in a Fargate cluster

Tags: aws-fargate

In fargate, I am deploying different applications in same cluster. Each application is running in different service and they have their own task. 
Say, Service1 --> 2 task running in port 8080
Service2 --> 2 task running in port 8080.
I get an error "Container is excited" and task is not started.

Comment: It's a good practice to add as much detail as you can to your question. For starters, you can add an excerpt of the log generated for experts to have a better understanding of what's happening.